# Displaying the App version in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, version

I want to display my current app version in a TextView, the activity the Textview is in is not my MainACtivity.
I used the folowing code:

```
public class informatie extends ActionBarActivity {

    public String versionName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatie);

        try {
           versionName = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Typeface impact = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Impact.ttf");

        TextView versieVak = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.versieView);
        versieVak.setText(versionName);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KLIK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        versieVak.setTypeface(impact);
        versieVak.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.antraciet));
        versieVak.setTextSize(10, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);

    }
```

The Layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.KnapperDev.knapper.jrw.informatie">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/overeenkomst"
            android:layout_marginBottom="249dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/versieView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="155dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But when i open the activity on my phone there is nothing in the TextView.
I made a Toast to check if `versieVak.setText(versionName);` was used.
it just doesn't display anything. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Gradle, you can greatly simplify this by using `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`.

Comment: The Toast does fire right?

Comment: @Samurai   yes it does

Comment: If you set a text to that TV in the layout, you'll see it? If so, try a different textColor and textSize in your code.

Comment: @Samurai   even when I delete all the styling parts of the code, it still doesn't show, so this shouldn't really be the problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this :

```
    // Import the BuildConfig at the top of the file
    import yourpackagename.BuildConfig
    
    ...

    // in your method, just use:
    TextView versionName = findViewById(R.id.textName);
    versionName.setText("version : " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

Comment: Smart and convenient.

Answer (score 5):

I tried using your code. It worked fine. Just remove your font related code and try simply. Check if it is working.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String versionName = "";
    try {
           versionName = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    TextView versionname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);
    versionname.setText(versionName);
}
```

Also make sure you have assigned unique ids for your textview.
If possible, can you share your layout?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
                    I just get: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.KnapperDev.knapper.jrw, PID: 18174
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.KnapperDev.knapper.jrw/com.KnapperDev.knapper.jrw.informatie}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @MalumAtire832, you said that the activity that the textview is in, is not your mainactivity. The activity that the TextView is in, are you displaying that? Because, unless android calls the onCreate of this activity, where your TextView is in, this code is not going to get executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Kotlin-

From activity:

```kotlin
var versionName = applicationContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(applicationContext.packageName, 0).versionName
yourTextView.text = "Version $versionName"
```

From fragment:

```kotlin
var versionName = requireActivity().applicationContext.packageManager.getPackageInfo(requireActivity().applicationContext.packageName, 0).versionName
yourTextView.text = "Version $versionName"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
textView.setText("App version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME + "("+BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE+")");
```